# Cannot launch Gazebo

Tags: ros, ubuntu, gazebo-11, ros-noetic

I have been learning and using ROS noetic on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. My OS is shown below, I excecuted "**lsb_release -a**".

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I have installed Gazebo11, and when I try to launch from the command line by executing "**gazebo**" I get the following:

```
gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I executed the following and still get the same above error:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

My environment variables are:

```
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=noetic
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib
```

The following command does not work:

> sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-simulator-gazebo

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-simulator-gazebo
```

The following command does not work either:

> udo apt-get install ros-noetic-ros-gz

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-ros-gz
```

I have an NVIDIA T1000, NVIDIA Driver Version 525.125.06

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you